# How does this value assignment work?

Tags: c

I'm reading K&R and the following code confuses me. Can someone explain it to me please. Thanks in advance.

```
int leap;
leap = year%4 == 0 && year%100 !=0 || year%400 == 0;
```

Comment: What you need to understand ?
What is leap year or what is `%` operator or how `leap` is evaluated ?

Comment: Why is this such a great question? If you have K&R, you head over to the part that explains operators, you grab a pencil and a sheet of paper and work it out.

Comment: @H2CO3 I understand the operators and the leap year but this assignment without parenthesis is new to me.

Comment: @user1650755 Why would you need any parentheses for an assignment? The assignment operator is `=`, not `()`...

Comment: @H2CO3 Because it is more understandable to me

Answer (score 12, accepted):

`leap` is assigned the result of the conditional expressions.

Putting parenthesis around it might make it a little easier to follow:

```
leap = ((year % 4 == 0) && (year % 100 !=0) || (year % 400 == 0));
```

You will get 0 if this didn't evaluate to true and 1 otherwise.

E.g. for `year = 2012` you get the following:

`(year % 4 == 0)` - this is true so this is equal to 1

(`year % 100  != 0)` - this is not true so again equal to 1

`(year % 400 == 0)` - not true and equal to 0

Then substituting these expressions with their value we get:

`leap = 1 && 1 || 0;` - which gives us back 1;

Comment: Its common knowledge that leap years occur every 4 years, but less people may be aware of the additional conditions captured in this statement. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Leap_year#Algorithm

Comment: @AtomicToothbrush while this is generally the case as you say the additional checks (such as the century check for example) are important as 1900 is not a leap year even though 1896 and 1904 are.

Answer (score 3):

The intention is to assign a 1 to `leap` if `year` is a leap year, and 0 to `leap` if `year` is not a leap year.

`year` is a leap year if it is divisible by 4 and not divisible by 100, or if `year` is divisible by 400. Otherwise, it is not. The right hand side of the assignment is the C code translation for this leap year rule.

`year%4 == 0` is true if `year` is divisible by 4.
`&&` is and.
`year%100 !=0` is true if `year` is not divisible by 100.
`||` is or.
`year%400 == 0` is true if `year` is divisible by 400.

Answer (score 3):

It will return true(1) or false(0). You can even set your leap to be a boolean.

```
int leap;
leap = year%4 == 0 && year%100 !=0 || year%400 == 0;
```

Assume your year is 2000.

```
leap = 2000%4 == 0 && 2000%100 !=0 || 2000%400 == 0
leap = true(1) && false(0) || true(1)
leap =false(0) || true(1)
leap = 1;
```

Always use paranthesis to avoid confusions. In this case you will not find any confusions because the precedence is left to right.

This is how the statement will be executed.

```
%, ==, !=, &&, ||
```

Comment: In C, the `||` and `&&` operators result in either `1` or `0`, not `true` or `false`.

Comment: @dreamlax i put it like that for explanation purpose. I have edited it.

Answer (score 1):

Basically, the result of the conditions is assigned to **leap**. 
The order of operation is simply

1.

```
year%4 == 0
```

2.

```
year%100 !=0
```

3.

```
 Result from 1 && Result from 2
```

4.

```
 year%400 == 0
```

5.

```
 Result from 3 || Result from 4
```

6.

```
  leap = Result from 5
```

Hope the explanation is clear and it helps.

Answer (score 1):

Alright, you already got some nice answers.

In short,

`%` gives remainder

`&&` is logical AND operation

variable `leap` evaluates to `1` if the condition holds true else `0`

Here's another way to calculate leap year :

```
leap = ((year & 3) == 0 && ((year % 25) != 0 || (year & 15) == 0));
```

Comment: Thanks for providing a new way